# Fill data in current row in a C# datagridview from a database according to the value just entered in a cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

My `datagridview` has 5 header which are

```
Item_code, Item_desc,Item_qty,Item_rate,Item_total.
```

Now from this user should enter only `Item_desc` & `Item qty`. The Cell `Item_desc` will autocomplete the string user enter. So once after user enter the `item_desc` I want the application to fill out rest of cells with corresponding details. And then user will enter the quantity and application should calculate and show `Item total` in respective cell. But I couldn't go further from `autocomplete` property for the `item_desc` column. Please help. Thanks in advance. Here I am attaching the screen shot of my application.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdWiJ.jpg)

Comment: No screenshot added yet..anyway, you want help with all these thing !?

Comment: So, where do you get the data from ?

Comment: data is from database only..from Items table..user will enter item desc(name only). And rest of the details should be given by application

Comment: ow..so , u want to fill in one row of the dgvw depending on the desc ?

Comment: yes..but user may enter more than one rows..so for each row application fill the data according to the item_desc user entered

Comment: okay :)...I am posting the answer now :)

Comment: Is the user supposed to know the exact item_description you have stored in your database? Approximately how many items will be in this table?

Comment: @Mary : Item_desc is item name only..it is the easiest way to enter item in grid view for user..Entering the items by item_code is not possible..the problem u mentioned will occur. User is not suppose to know or remember all the item_code in database. But he can type item name(desc). And I added auto complete property for that cell..so thr wont be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL database,it should not be that hard :

```
  private void datagridview1_KeyDown()
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      {
       int rowindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex; //Here we get the selected row's index of the dataGridView
       int columnindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex; ////Here we get the selected column's index of the dataGridView
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tablename WHERE desc=@desc",connection);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@desc",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
       SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       While (dr.Read())
        {
          dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Value = dr[1].ToString
         ///Keep continuing for each column
        }
       dr.Close();
       }
```

Comment: are you sure its e.keycode ? Because its an error showing..Saying doesnt contain definition for keycode

Comment: sorry, my bad, move the code to the `KeyDown` event

Comment: ow and if this solves your issue, make sure to mark it as the answer :)

Comment: its not working zack..But the logic seems fine..So I tried the same with cell leave even also by changing the if condition.But still no use..

Comment: it worked partially zack..it wont fill rest of column once I press tab from item desc (i changed <key.Enter> to <key.Tab>). but if I come back to the desc column and press tab again then the data is populated. But now its another headache. My insert is not working now with this. I insert these datas to invoice table.saying input string is not correct. i posted it as another question just now

Comment: atlast i found it..its more better to use CellEndEdit event. Now I can get data right after I leave the focus on a cell..Thanks @zack.  base idea is urs only

Answer (score 0):

At last I found I can do both in same event handler function.

//to fill item details in each row when item description entry is done
//to show item total in each row when quantity entry is done

<

```
private void dtgrdvw_items_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                int rowindex = dtgrdvw_items.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                int columnindex = dtgrdvw_items.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from item WHERE item_desc=@inv_item_desc", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@inv_item_desc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dtgrdvw_items.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    dtgrdvw_items.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Value = dr[0].ToString();
                    dtgrdvw_items.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Value = dr[1].ToString();
                    dtgrdvw_items.Rows[rowindex].Cells[3].Value = dr[2].ToString();
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
         if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
            {

                int cell1 = Convert.ToInt32(dtgrdvw_items.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);

                Decimal cell2 = Convert.ToDecimal(dtgrdvw_items.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);

                if (cell1.ToString() != "" && cell2.ToString() != "")
                {

                    dtgrdvw_items.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value = cell1 * cell2;

                }
            }
        }
```

>

Here in CellEndEdit I checked the index of current column and retrieve item details from item table once I enter item description(column 2). Then after I enter quantity (column 3) it will calculate with rate (column 4) and show total instantaneously in total column (column 5)..Thanks for the helps